# how do we send null values to a db using xml?

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to pass null values to a db through xml.

```
            <parameter>
                <key>email</key>
                <value>tester@memoir-systems.com</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <key>password</key>
                <value></value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <key>Customer</key>
                <value/>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <key>Address</key>
                <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </parameter>
```

I've tried all this but it is taking it as a empty string with length zero and not as a null .

```
my xsd is

<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="testCaseData" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:long" name="id" minOccurs="0"/>     
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="testCaseName"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="expectedResult"/>
              <xs:element name="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="key"/>
                    <xs:element name="value"  maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Can anyone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check it on server side if the value is empty then insert null in your db.